# How to add a hatch background to a circle in folium?

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

Is there any way to add a pattern fill such as a hatch background in folium? It is possible to use a hatch fill for polygons using a GeoJSON object and folium.plugins.StripePattern (https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/tests/plugins/test_pattern.py) but I haven't seen an implementation with circle and haven't had much luck playing around with it.

The feature is available in leaflet with https://github.com/teastman/Leaflet.pattern, for example:

```
        var myPattern = new L.StripePattern({ angle: -45, weight: 3, color: 'black', opacity: 1.0});
        myPattern.addTo(m);
        var circle = new L.Circle([42, -105], 40000, {fillPattern: myPattern, fillOpacity: 1.0});
        circle.addTo(m);
```

Worst case scenario I can write the leaflet code directly to the html file.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function to work around my issue. The arguments of the function are numpy arrays of the circle positions (longitude/latitude) and a float for the radius of the circles in meters.

```
#Function to inject leaflet hatching code for circles
def injectHatch_f(xO_v, yO_v, rO):

    #Get map name
    mName = m.get_name()

    #Generate javascript (note use of Jinja2 tags to place javascript code after map is initialized): https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/854
    js = '''{{% macro script(this, kwargs) %}}
    var myPattern = new L.StripePattern({{ angle: -45, weight: 3, color: 'black', opacity: 1.0}});
    myPattern.addTo({0});
    '''.format(mName) + \
    '\n'.join(["var circle = new L.Circle([{1}, {2}], {3}, {{fillPattern: myPattern, fillOpacity: 1.0}}).addTo({0});".format(mName, yO_v[i], xO_v[i], rO) for i in range(xO_v.shape[0])]) + \
    '{% endmacro %}'

    #Add leaflet pattern plugin
    m.get_root().html.add_child(JavascriptLink('https://teastman.github.io/Leaflet.pattern/leaflet.pattern.js'))

    #Inject javascript code
    element = folium.MacroElement().add_to(m)
    element._template = jinja2.Template(js)
```